# Force improper comparisons to throw a warning/error in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, runtime-error

I had JavaScript code similar to the following:

```
var data = {"d": 12345};
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; ++i) {
    console.log(i);
}
```

I know that this for loop will not execute any cycles because data.length will be 'undefined' and

```
0 < 'undefined' //false (I think this is false for any int?)
```

Anyways, while I fixed my code (in my code, data contains an array but I was accidentally referencing data.length instead of data.myarr.length) I'm hoping to avoid such problems in the future - took me quite some time to find this bug.

I have been reading up on [strict mode in JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope/Strict_mode) but after [messing around with JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/35JcS/) I couldn't get strict mode to throw the above as an error. I tried both making the entire script strict, then, thinking maybe there was a conflict, tried it within its own method and still got nothing.

Is there a way to force "nonsensical" comparisons such as int < "undefined" to throw an error (or even a warning)? Did I miss something with strict mode? Or is the language design supposed to allow such things?

Comment: I don't know that this is possible, but I'm not one of those language aficionados who can say with certainty anything of the like. My first stab at it, would be to try and create some kind of helper function which performs comparisons for you, throwing exceptions for non-matching inputs or improper results.

Comment: Yeah. I know how to check for undefined, and I don't need to do it in my code really. I'm just trying to save myself and others dev time in the future.

Comment: Yeah, the only way I can see, would be to make a standardized comparison function that you and your entire team uses for all comparisons of that nature, erecting exceptions as an early warning system. Probably not fantabulous for edge optimization cases that could jump out introducing such a thing =/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing within Javascript itself that will pick this one up.

I haven't kept track of the latest developments in [JS Lint](http://www.jslint.com/), but I don't know of anything there that would help.

On the other hand, [TypeScript](http://www.typescriptlang.org/) handles this situation very well.

Just as head's up -- this isn't something that *can* change in Javascript without breaking existing code.  There are enough `array like` objects that have a both a `length` property and numericly named property names that one iterates over.

- The `arguments` keyword
- Node lists

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, there's no real way to achieve what you're after. since `int < undefined` is a perfectly fine comparison.

One thing you could do, for this specific issue, is use Array.forEach ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)). This would throw an error since `data.forEach` is `undefined` and attempting to call that as a function will fail (*unless you added a "forEach" key on data with a function value, of course*):

```
var data = {"d": 12345};
data.forEach(function(item, index, array){
    console.log(index);
});
```

Note, that IE < 9 does not have Array.forEach, so you would need to add it to Array's prototype. See more here, including how to do so, at [Array.prototype.forEach() on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach).

Comment: Not a bad idea, though in my actual code I'm very reliant on using the value of i. I could create a counter outside var the loop, but hoping not to. I'm more familiar with Java, but do you know if JavaScript has a performance hit by doing forEach instead of for? (Specifically, does it create a copy of the current object temporarily?)

Comment: @MatthewHerbst ah, you do get the index, as the second argument in the callback... should have included that. I've changed the answer :)

Comment: Oh, sweet! Thanks! I gave the answer to the other post because you guys basically said the same thing, but he beat you by a few minutes. But I really do appreciate the forEach idea/info! Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

In ES6, you could use an iterator via `for...of`, which would result in an error since non-array objects are not iterable:

```
for (var x of data) { }
```

You will have make other arrangements if you also want the index.